# facebook Prophet - Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, facebook-prophet

we are using FB Prophet for forecasting, and it is working fine.Forecasting runs every 5 days.

I'm trying to enable backfill i.e. if there is processing issue resulting in gaps in forecasting, I want to be able to get the forecast for past days.

Here is the code for this :

```
@pandas_udf(result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def forecast_sent_recv(self, history_pd):

        print(" in forecast_sent_recv ")
        print(" history_pd ", history_pd[['applianceName','timeslot','cktName','tenantName']])

        history_pd[['applianceName','timeslot','cktName','tenantName']].head(5)

        # changing to timeslot_date, since timeslot is now in utc
        history_pd['ds'] = history_pd['timeslot_date']
        # 09/25/2023 - change for change
        #curr_day = datetime.date.today()
        curr_day = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        today = np.datetime64(curr_day)
        week1 = np.datetime64(curr_day + datetime.timedelta(days=7))

        history_pd = history_pd[history_pd['ds'] < today]
        # history_pd = history_pd.dropna(thresh=2)
        print(" earliest date in history_pd, ascending=False ")
        print(history_pd.sort_values(by='timeslot', ascending=False).head(1))

        print(" latest date in history_pd, ascending=True ")
        print(history_pd.sort_values(by='timeslot', ascending=True).head(1))

        curr_pd = None
        for pred in ['sentOctets', 'recvdOctets']:
            history_pd['y'] = history_pd[pred].astype('int64')

            # print(" history_pd.shape :: ", history_pd.shape, " history_pd.shape[0] :: ", history_pd.shape[0])

            # instantiate the model, configure the parameters
            model = Prophet()

            model.fit(history_pd)

            # configure predictions for y days
            future_pd = model.make_future_dataframe(
                periods=100800,
                freq='10min',
                include_history=True
            )

            # This is needed instead of just selecting lesser period because
            # empty frames due to a failure in streaming job causes old data
            # to be generated
            future_pd = future_pd[future_pd['ds'] >= today]
            future_pd = future_pd[future_pd['ds'] <= week1]
            
            ....... (Additional Code)







results = (
            all_DF
                .dropna()
                .withColumn('total_rows', f_count('applianceName').over(window))
                .where(col('total_rows') > lit(100))
                .drop('total_rows')
                .groupBy('applianceName', 'cktName')
                .apply(self.forecast_sent_recv)
                .withColumn('training_date', current_date())
        )
```

all_DF.dropna() is called before the pandas_udf forecast_sent_recv() is called.
This should drop all rows with any None columns.

However, I get the following error when i run this on the fill dataset.

```
 count in all_DF :: 1657436
/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/group_ops.py:81: UserWarning: It is preferred to use 'applyInPandas' over this API. This API will be deprecated in the future releases. See SPARK-28264 for more details.
23/09/29 18:10:40 INFO org.apache.arrow.memory.BaseAllocator: Debug mode disabled.
23/09/29 18:10:40 INFO org.apache.arrow.memory.DefaultAllocationManagerOption: allocation manager type not specified, using netty as the default type
23/09/29 18:10:40 INFO org.apache.arrow.memory.CheckAllocator: Using DefaultAllocationManager at memory-netty-2.0.0.jar!/org/apache/arrow/memory/DefaultAllocationManagerFactory.class
23/09/29 18:10:50 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 144.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 560) (versa-intf-rate-predict-backfill-v1-w-3.c.versa-sml-googl.internal executor 12): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 604, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 596, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/serializers.py", line 273, in dump_stream
    return ArrowStreamSerializer.dump_stream(self, init_stream_yield_batches(), stream)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/serializers.py", line 81, in dump_stream
    for batch in iterator:
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/serializers.py", line 266, in init_stream_yield_batches
    for series in iterator:
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 429, in mapper
    return f(keys, vals)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 170, in <lambda>
    return lambda k, v: [(wrapped(k, v), to_arrow_type(return_type))]
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 158, in wrapped
    result = f(key, pd.concat(value_series, axis=1))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/2eec4e36-fc45-4190-a2b8-a3422444f5c3/predictions_backfill_v1.py", line 157, in forecast_sent_recv
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prophet/forecaster.py", line 1116, in fit
    raise ValueError('Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows.')
ValueError: Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows.

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:505)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:508)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Note ; when this run this for a single applianceId, the code goes through.

Also, to backfill - the following change is made:

```
# curr_day is set to : today - 7 days 
curr_day = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
today = np.datetime64(curr_day)
week1 = np.datetime64(curr_day + datetime.timedelta(days=7))
# take history data < today
history_pd = history_pd[history_pd['ds'] < today]


# include_history is set to true
future_pd = model.make_future_dataframe(
                periods=100800,
                freq='10min',
                include_history=True
            )
```

any ideas on how to fix/debug this ?